# Access a ViewController instance and call a methdod from AppDelegate, ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS /swift programming.

The app I am working is essentially a music player and the music has to be played also in background, giving the possibility to play/pause/skip from the lock screen. The app has several views, one of them, the main one, contains all the code related to the player itself (PlayerVC.swift), the other ones containing other additional pages/features. All the views are accessible through a menu, implemented using ECSlidingViewController.

In AppDelegate I have added the code needed to detect the use of remote controls:

```
override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent) {
if (event.type == UIEventType.RemoteControl) {
    switch (event.subtype) {
    case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay:
        ...
    case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPause:
      ...
    case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
       ....
    case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlNextTrack:
        PlayerVC.onNext(nil)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

}

For each of the case I need to call a method in PlayerVC (e.g. the onNext method, I kno that `PlayerVC.onNext(nil)` is not enough), using the current instance of PlayerVC and not creating a new instance. I am very confused about how to achieve this, I've found many similar questions here but none of them solved my issue, some of theme were in objective C (I'm developing in swift) some other produced errors. According to my tests, it seems that the presented view controller is always ECSlidingViewController and I guess (but I am not sure) that the tricky part in my case is exactly this one.

Comment: I had the same situation. I solved it by creating a manager singleton class for the music player which can be accessed from anywhere. Your view controller can also use the shared instance then to render controls accordingly. I hope I have a clear understanding of your problem

Comment: thanks for the comment; I've tried the singleton solution without success, probably because I'm doing something wrong. Ideally I would like to modify as little code as possible because I'm fixing an app built by someone else. Could you explain your solution in an answer? Is there an easy way to just access the current instance of PlayerVC from AppDelegate?

Comment: My solution is in Objective-C and not in swift. I can post that if that helps but I'm on a mobile device right now. The ECSlidingViewController has a property called the frontViewController which should give you the top view controller which is currently active. Access your root view controller (which should be your sliding view controller, and then access frontViewController and type cast it) But this approach would only work in case your top view controller is actually the PlayerVC and not other VC. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment; the view controller currently active can actually be a different one. This is the reason why I am implementing remoteControlReceivedWithEvent in AppDelegate otherwise I could have implemented it in PlayerVC.swift (as it was before, and it worked well but not if the user locked the device from a view different than the PlayerVC).
So there isn't any way to directly refer to a specific View Controller? It has to be the active one?

Comment: Yes, I thought so as I had the same issue. The way the sliding view controller works is that it only keeps the current VC live and removes the previous one from the view hierarchy. I think the singleton approach is the best way to move forward. If you want I can post the obj-c code as an example and you can try to convert it to swift?

Comment: A few things I found while doing a quick search, have a look at these for a starting point : https://gist.github.com/irichardson/1af5dca4a48ac8f6e571 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908760/how-do-i-get-music-to-persist-as-i-navigate-from-view-to-view Let me know if you'd like to see the ObjC code that I have. Thanks.

Comment: The fact that the sliding vc removes it from the hierarchy prevents me to access its methods? The player is actually still active, if I leave it plays, it goes on so I guess I can in some way get it? About the singletone class I guess I need to move some of the methods out of my PlayerVC file, right? This would be probably tricky to do for me, I am not sure about how to integrate it with the remaining part of PlayerVC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91787/discussion-between-gurtej-singh-and-eugenio).

Comment: @GurtejSingh I wrote you in the chat! :)